# convert time to date format in R

Tags: r, date, time

I am trying to change the class of a variable from "time" to "date". The column I am trying to change is the result of an Oracle query executed by ROracle package.

The column is in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" but the class is not date... when I try to change it to date with the function `as.Date(min_date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')` the console returns the following error:

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

```
min_date <- structure(c(1335909600, 1336946400, 1336514400, 1336514400, 1335045600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

Comment: can you `dput` your data ?

Comment: it is a large vector but here is a chunk of it: structure(c(1335909600, 1336946400, 1336514400, 1336514400, 1335045600, ....) class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))     reconstructed it looks like this "2012-08-29 CEST"

Comment: With your data I haven't got the error. Are you sure that the sapmle you posted returns the error ?

Comment: I tried ` as.Date("2012-08-29 CEST", format="%Y-%m-%d")`. And gave `"2012-08-29".

Answer (score 0):

```
min_date <- structure(c(1335909600, 1336946400, 1336514400, 1336514400, 1335045600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
min_date <- as.Date(min_date)
class(min_date)
```

returns "Date"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the comments,by reading your comments I realized that as.Date should be done outside the select statement I was doing (forgot to mention that, sorry)

This is the original code:

```
temp <- select(data, name,as.Date(MIN_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  summarise(MIN_DATE = min(MIN_DATE))%>%
  arrange(MIN_DATE)
```

and this the solution

```
temp <- select(data, name,MIN_DATE)%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  summarise(MIN_DATE = min(MIN_DATE))%>%
  arrange(MIN_DATE)

temp$MIN_DATE<- as.Date(temp$MIN_DATE, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Hope this helps to someone else working with dplyr